# Дата published_at в модели - ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель - `Post`, если в параметрах не передается поле - `published_at`, то мне необходимо проставить текущую дату времени на момент создания объекта `Post`. Прописываю в модели соответствующий колбэк, но он у меня не работает почему-то.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :date_published_post 

  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

  def date_published_post
   if  self.published_at.nil?
    self.published_at = Time.now
  end

  end

end
```

Comment: Возможно вас устроит поле created_at, которое по-умолчанию хранит время создания объекта. А что касается колбека, мне видится код верным, может уточните вопрос командами rails-консоли...

Comment: created_at понятно , по задумке просто при создании можно передать дату публикации поста,а если не передается то поставить текущую.          в rails консоле ввожу : 'u.posts.create(title:"пост №19",body: "про погоду сегодня")' создается объект в котором published_at =    nil '
   (11.7ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Post id: 25, title: "пост №19", body: "про погоду сегодня", published_at: nil, user_id: 10, created_at: "2017-10-16 06:26:09", updated_at: "2017-10-16 06:26:09"> 
'

Comment: Возьмите отладчик, поставьте точку останова внутри `date_published_post` и изучите сложившееся внутри состояние (`self` и атрибуты).